# How can I take value from HTML code?

Tags: java, jsoup

I have this code:

```
<div id="g4iloprop">
<h4>HF propagation conditions: <span class="date">2012 Sep 19 1205 UTC</span></h4>
<p><b><span title="10.7cm solar flux">Solar flux:</span></b> 104<img src="nc.gif" alt="no change" hspace="2" /> <b><span title="Mid-latitude A Index">A:</span></b> 8<img
```

Prompt please as to me to take value 104 which is between tags `</b> 104<img`

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
String html = // your html here

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
Elements elements = doc.select("b + img");


for( Element e : elements )
{
    Node value = e.previousSibling();

    // eg. print the node, here the output is 104 and 8
    System.out.println(value.toString());
}
```

If you only need the first value, you can replace the for-Loop with this:

```
Node value = elements.first().previousSibling();
```